# Why is pd.qcut() producing massive boundaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have a dataframe of event data of which a column is the interval of time in which that event occurred. I would like to use `pd.qcut()` to make the percentiles of each interval given the events that are in it, and give each event its respective percentile.

```py
def event_quartiler(event_row):
    in_interval = paired_events.loc[events['TimeInterval'] == event_row['TimeInterval']]
    quartiles = pd.qcut(in_interval['DateTime'], 100)
    counter = 1
    for quartile in quartiles.unique():
        if(event_row['DateTime'] in quartile):
            return counter
        counter = counter+1
        if(counter > 100): break
    return -1

events['Quartile'] = events.apply(event_quartiler, axis=1)
```

I expected that this would simply set the Quartile column to each event's respective percentile, but instead the code takes forever to run and effectively blows out by outputting this:

```py
ValueError: ("Bin edges must be unique: array([1.55016605e+18, 1.55016616e+18, 1.55016627e+18, 1.55016632e+18,\n       1.55016632e+18, 1.55016636e+18,
... (I put the ellipsis here because there are 100 data points) 
1.55017534e+18, 1.55017545e+18,\n       1.55017555e+18]).\nYou can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg", 'occurred at index 6539')
```

There is nothing different about the data at 6539 or any of the events in its interval, but I cannot find where I am going wrong with the code either.

Comment: I am not actually sure if I can...the code works up until the 6539th row and then throws that problem. So would it be reasonable to make a dataframe with the types that I'm talking about and post it here? I'm sorry, I'm new and don't really know the standards here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem: qcut tries to fit all of the data points themselves into quartiles while cut takes the min and max and cuts into n bins. Because in this example I had more quartiles that I was trying to make than actual datapoints, qcut was failing.

Just using cut into 100 bins solved my problem and I was able to make percentiles.